# Limit Linux DMA allocation to specific range

Tags: linux-kernel, dma

I am working on a SOC which it's RAM starts at 0x200M.
For some reason I need to limit the DMA allocations up to 0x220M, so I called  - `dma_set_mask_and_coherent(dev, 0x21FFFFFFF)`.
I noticed that
`dev->dma_mask`  was not set, while
`dev->coherent_dma_mask` was set.
Still, calling dma_alloc_coherent returns buffers above the requested limit.
How can I limit the buffer address?

Comment: Please post the code needed to show the problem.

Comment: It's nothing but:  
`dma_set_mask_and_coherent(mmc_dev(mmc), 0x21FFFFFFF)`

Comment: I have never known a DMA mask to be anything other than a power of 2 minus 1.

Comment: Ian - I thought so too, but found  [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/543408/) - look for 0xc3ffffff example